# Why did my reputation increase for 'removed'?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I got a mysterious +1 reputation boost today for:

```
5 hours ago removed Eclipse recent files
```

I guess this means the page 'Eclipse recent files' has been removed (it is not presented as a link above).

Why did my reputation increase for that?

Comment: You had downvoted the person's answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You downvoted an answer on the [Eclipse recent files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116092/eclipse-recent-files) question.

When you did so, you lost 1 point reputation; downvotes on answers always cost rep. When it was deleted 5 hours ago, your vote was undone and the rep you lost for the vote was refunded.

You were not the only one to have downvoted it; it had a score of -1, 3 downvotes and 2 upvotes for:

> Unfortunately Eclipse sucks, so this is not supported in any acceptable form.

which isn't really an answer; the revision history shows it was [deleted from the Low Quality review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4741058).

Comment: I thought you lose 2 points when you down vote an answer and 1 point when you down vote a question.  Is this not the case?

Comment: No, that is not the case. You lose 2 points when someone else downvotes your question or answer. You lose 1 point when *you* downvote an answer, 0 when you downvote a question.